# is there an academic name for this one polyline shape?

Tags: geometry

this figure looks like a contour though, there is only one line

[image]

is there an academic name for this shape?

Comment: It's a triangle.

Comment: I don't thjnk so, but it's elegant. Did you encounter it in a mathematical setting?

Comment: @EthanBolker i would like to find a mathematical method to calculate this kind of shape, but i don't know the keyword to search

Comment: It would be relatively easy to write a computer program to draw this, but I doubt that a search will find one already written.

Comment: writing a computer program is what i need to do, would you plz give a hint about this? a formula or a mathematical rule would be appreciated

Comment: I would call it an Archimedean (right isoceles) triangular spiral, but that's nothing standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this spiral (or something very like it) can be drawn by segments connecting the following points:
\begin{align}
&(-r,  r) \\
&(r,-r) \\
&(-r,-r) \\
&(-2r,2r) \\
&(2r,-2r) \\
&(-2r,-2r) \\
&(-3r,3r) \\
&(3r,-3r) \\
&(-3r,-3r) \\
&(-4r,4r) \\
&(4r,-4r) \\
&(-4r,-4r) \\
&\ldots
\end{align}

That is, draw a segment from each point to the next one in the sequence.
Choose a value of $r$ that makes the picture look right; if $r$ is too small you will just get a solid black triangle. The right value of $r$ may depend on the software you use.

Each "upward" line from $(-kr,-kr)$ to $(-(k+1)r, (k+1)r)$ makes an angle that is slightly to the left of "straight up." This is more evident in the inner part of the triangle, especially the upward segment from $(-r,-r)$ to $(-2r,2r).$
If you wanted that segment to be vertical (unlike the segments in the picture),
you could replace each point that has coordinates $(-kr,-kr)$
with one at $(-(k+1)r,-kr).$

Comment: `x = np.array([-1.,  1., -1., -2.,  2., -2., -3.,  3., -3.]);y = np.array([ 1., -1., -1.,  2., -2., -2.,  3., -3., -3.]);plt.plot(x,y)` is this a correct implementation?

Comment: You'll need a lot more points before it starts to look like the picture in the question, but you seem to have the right start. You've set $r=1,$ which might be OK depending on the software you use; does it draw something that looks like the middle of your picture?

Comment: thanks your excellent work! let's keep this post to discuss the naming. i just opened another post to discuss the implementation, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3243386/649828

Comment: Based on the figure in the followup, it looks like I goofed one part of this: the lower left corners walk down to the left at an angle of 45 degrees, but the upper left has to go up faster than it goes left and the lower right has to go right faster than it goes down. You could try doubling all the positive coordinates; that might work better.