# how can i draw a specific space-filling curve mathematically? almost achieve, need a bug fixing.

Tags: computational-geometry, python

here is a figure (fig_1) illustrating a space-filling spiral curve constitutes a triangle.

[image]

i am trying to draw this mathematically.

with @David K's help, we got this figure (fig_2)

[image: draw a space-filling curve]

by using this formula

\begin{align}
&(-r,  r) \\
&(r,-r) \\
&(-r,-r) \\
&(-2r,2r) \\
&(2r,-2r) \\
&(-2r,-2r) \\
&(-3r,3r) \\
&(3r,-3r) \\
&(-3r,-3r) \\
&(-4r,4r) \\
&(4r,-4r) \\
&(-4r,-4r) \\
&\ldots
\end{align}

here is a piece of python code to implement the formula

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([])
y = np.array([])
for r in range(1,9):
    x = np.append(x, np.array([-r,r,-r]))
    y = np.append(y, np.array([r,-r,-r]))
plt.plot(x,y)
```

fig_2 is very close to fig_1 though, there seems to be a bug. how to improve this formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to @David K

doubling all the positive coordinates might work better

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([])
y = np.array([])
for r in range(9):
    x = np.append(x, np.array([-r,2*r,-r]))
    y = np.append(y, np.array([2*r,-r,-r]))
plt.plot(x,y)
```

outputs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLczl.png)